# Setting up OAUTH on Drupal 7 for iOS 5

Tags: ios5, drupal-7

I am working on iOS 5, and I have got all the needed modules enabled.
Can anyone tell me how to set up OATH on Drupal?

I need a step by step procedure on both Drupal 7 and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking a look at the services module: http://drupal.org/project/services . You can expose OAuth authentication with that.

There's probably too many application specific variables to get a good step by step for how you need to consume it on the IOS side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try reading up and was able to configure drupal but I am not sure on how to go about with iOS.

Comment: You asked a pretty broad question. Try closing this question and asking a more specific question for IOS, with details on what you are considering from research and any relevant info about the IOS side of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this guide:

[Using oAuth with the Drupal iOS SDK](http://www.workhabit.com/blog/using-oauth-drupal-ios-sdk)

Basically what you want is to include in your iOS project the Drupal-iOS sdk [which can be download from here](https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk) and then follow the instructions on the first link.